# How to get the session id from http header in java?

Tags: java, session

How can I get the session id from the http header using java?
I tried this code but the session id is not here:

```
public class TESTHttp {
    private static String USER_AGENT;

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {

            URL obj = new URL("https://mysite.com");
            URLConnection conn = obj.openConnection();
            Map<String, List<String>> map = conn.getHeaderFields();

            System.out.println("Printing All Response Header for URL: "
                    + obj.toString() + "\n");

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
            }

            System.out.println("\nGet Response Header By Key ...\n");
            List<String> contentLength = map.get("Content-Length");

            if (contentLength == null) {
                System.out
                .println("'Content-Length' doesn't present in Header!");
            } else {
                for (String header : contentLength) {
                    System.out.println("Content-Lenght: " + header);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything missing in my code?

Comment: If it's not there, the server didn't send one.

Comment: It's probably a cookie.

Comment: The problem is how to get the session id from http header for https site, for other site it's working

Comment: There is no difference between HTTP and HTTPS when it comes to the headers.